# Show a default placeholder in a select VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a select with VueJS but i cannot seem to have a placeholder pre-selected and disabled like normal. The below i am trying to have "Choose your saved prescription" be the default on load. What currently loads is a blank select, with the placeholder as an option but not the first loaded option. My v-model loads as an empty object.

```
<select v-model="selectedPrescriptionChoice">
     <option value="" selected disabled>Choose your saved prescription</option>
     <option v-for="pre in prescriptionDataVue" :value="pre.prescriptionData">
                    ${ pre.prescriptionName } - ${ pre.prescriptionDateAdded }
     </option>
</select>

data: function () {
        return {
        selectedPrescriptionChoice: {}
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by assigning the value to the empty object. Which matches what my default v-model is. I tested it on all my other v-for selects and by putting the DEFAULT/MATCHED value of the v-model the placeholder works fine. Not sure why it was so hard to find an answer online.

```
 <select v-model="selectedPrescriptionChoice">
           <option :value="{}" selected disabled>
              Choose your saved prescription
            </option>
              <option v-for="pre in prescriptionDataVue" :value="pre.prescriptionData">
                    ${ pre.prescriptionName } - ${ pre.prescriptionDateAdded }
           </option>
    </select>
```